# Detach database with password

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am using C# and SMO to successfully detach and attach an SQL server database.

I was wondering if it is possible to password protect the detached database? Preferably via C# other suggestions also welcome. I am not too familiar with SQL Users and permissions.

(Background: We use a transfer database to transfer information to offsite units without internet connections via contractors. These databases have sensitive information. We would like that the information not be accessed by a savvy contractor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe does not have anything to do with SQL Server / SMO or whatever - just encrypt the files you want to transfer with some password and a good algorithm (like AES256) and keep the password secret between you and the offsite unit. Use a new cryptographically strong password for every transfer (never use a password twice!).

IF you want to verify that the file has not been tampered with create a digital signature for every encrypted file you transfer (use an asymmetric algorithm for that like RSA). you keep the private key a secret from everyone... for verification of the signature(s) the public key is sufficient - the public key can be known to the whole world without compromising your security.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestion, was kinda hoping that SQL Server had an ability to do this without me having to do it. Will probably go that route. On a side note, any suggestion on how to decrypt the file on the offsite as I doubt SMO has the ability to attach an mdf file from memory. (Edit: IE how to make the temporary decrypted file secure)

Comment: @Talib Attaching from memory is no guarantee for absolute security... to give any useful answer you need to give more information: What sort of risks / attack vectors are you trying to defend against exaclty ?

Comment: I wonder if memory-mapped files would be useful for this ... problem is transfer DB can several gigs big.

Comment: It is not a great security risk, we just want to prevent a savvy person attaching this database via SSMS on another machine and making alterations to any of the data ... well, I think I just figured out my own solution ... encrypt the data in the transfer database.